# How to create a one level nest in D3

Tags: d3.js, nested

I'm learning about nesting and have been looking at phoebe bright's explanations, where she writes:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.status; })
.entries(csv_data);
```

gets this:

```
 [
   {
      "key": "Complete",
      "values": [
         {
            "id": "T-024",
            "name": "Organisation list in directory",
            "priority": "MUST",
         },
         {
```

When I try to do the same, in my console, if I can recreate it, looks like this:

```
Object
   key: "1847"
   values: Array [2]
      0: Object
         production: "A Mirror for Witches"
      1: Object
         production: "Sadlers Wells"
```

When I try to display the "Values" as text, all I get is [Object, object] in my html, where what I want is the production names.

How do I do this? I have tried nesting production as a key also, but this doesn't seem to work, and have also tried returning the index when returning the values, but can't get that to work either.

Any help I will really appreciate, thanks.

Here is my code

**data.csv**

```
year,production,company
1847,A Mirror for Witches
1847,Sadlers Wells



d3.csv("data.csv", function(csv_data){

var nested_data = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d)  { return d.year; })
                .entries(csv_data)
                console.log(nested_data);

var selection =
d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
  .data(nested_data)
  .enter()

selection.append("div")
  .classed('classed', true)
  .text(function(d){
   return d.key;
   });

d3.selectAll(".classed").append("div")
   .text(function(d){
   return d.values;
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/0QuH8P9ujMdl0vWuQkrQ?p=preview

I added a few more lines of data to show it working properly.

The thing to do here is to add a second selection (I've called it `production_selection`) and bind data based off the first selection (`year_selection`): You use [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/#data) to show nested data.

First selection (show a div for each year, or key, in your nested data):

```
var year_selection = d3.select("#chart").selectAll("div")
    .data(nested_data)
    .enter().append("div")
    ...
```

Second selection (show all productions, or values, under that key):

```
var production_selection = year_selection.selectAll(".classed")
   .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
   .enter().append("div")
   ...
```

For the second selection, you just define the accessor function (`d.values`)

Comment: I've never seen it done that way before, that's brilliant! Thank you so much for your help.